# How to monitor HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

We have two HAProxy servers using keapalived for failover. Once one goes down, the other one takes over seamlessly.

I know it is possible to configure HAProxy to send an email to alert a sysadmin, but it would also be helpful to see the health n the HAProxy statistics page where all monitored services are displayed. (`hostname:1936/?stats`).

Is this possible? Currently we don't even know which one of the servers is serving the stats page.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is which node is the active one, then look at using the [stats show-node](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-stats%20show-node) directive.

Add it to your stats section and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. Now I know which node the stats are served from. However, it does not tell if the other HAProxy server is up or not.

Comment: Not sure, but that's a whole other question.

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/q/560024/266218) question might help you along with your *Is the other HAProxy server is up or not?* problem.